# How to access the Xamarin Forms App object from a ContentView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a ContentView that I use as shared code on my pages.  It contains navigation links etc.  In the ContentView, I am trying to access a method in my App class that has the following signature:

```
    public void ClearNavigationAndGoToPage(Page pobj_Page)
    {
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(pobj_Page);
    }
```

However, when I use the following line of code in a ContentView

```
App.ClearNavigationAndGoToPage(new nearbyplaces());
```

I get the following error message:

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'App.ClearNavigationAndGoToPage(Page)'

I can access the method from ContentPages just not ContentViews.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the method where you're trying to make the call from static?

Comment: I wanted to give Esteban credit because there was a problem because I had not marked the method as static.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use App.Current to access the instance of your app class.  You will need to cast it to the appropriate class before calling the custom method

```
((CustomType)App.Current).ClearNavigationAndGoToPage(new nearbyplaces());
```